# How to make AJAX call with angular2(ts)?

Tags: angular

How to make AJAX call  with angular2(ts)?
I read the tutorial on angularjs.org. But there is nothing about AJAX.
So I really want to know how to make AJAX call  with angular2(ts).

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial? I've been following it myself and it discusses AJAX requests part of the way in: http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-angular-2-using-typescript/

Comment: FYI angularjs.org is about AngularJS (ie. 1), whereas angular.io is about Angular (ie. 2 and more)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will want to look at the [api docs for the http module](https://angular.io/api?query=http). The [`http`](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) class can get resources for you using AJAX. See the Angular [HttpClient Guide](https://angular.io/guide/http) for more examples.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'http-app',
  templateUrl: 'people.html'
})
class PeopleComponent {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('people.json')
      // Call map on the response observable to get the parsed people object
      .map(res => res.json())
      // Subscribe to the observable to get the parsed people object and attach it to the
      // component
      .subscribe(people => this.people = people);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
    providers: [RemoteService]
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    allData = [];
    resu: string;
    errData: string;
    name: string = "Deepak";

    constructor(private http: Http){}

    ngOnInit(){}

    onSubmit(value: any) {
    //console.log(value.message);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify(value);
    this.http.post('127.0.0.1/myProject/insertData.php', body, headers)
                .subscribe(
                    () => {alert("Success")}, //For Success Response
                    err => {console.error(err)} //For Error Response
                );                
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### json-data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class JsonDataService {
  errorMessage: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

 getData(): Observable<JsonData[]> {
    console.log('Retriving Data from Server.......');
    return this.http.get('http://883.82.3:8086/restfullDataApi/UserService/jsondata')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

getSolrData() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = "http://883.8.2:8086/PI3_Solr_WebService/solrService"; /
    return this.http.post(url).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
   let body = res.json();
    return body || [];
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    alert("Server Error!");
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

Answer (score -5):

AJAX is fully transparent in angularjs, see the links and examples below.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

Comment: Sorry,i asked angular2.

Comment: the question is regarding angular 2 with typescript