# How to pass objects between server side node and client side angular 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

this is my first question on this forum. I'm just a newbie when it comes to developing web applications. I have a some code typical js (Twitter search/tweets) which runs on node. This code returns an json object based on specific keyword. The has to be supplied by the angular  component. So, basically I need to send the keyword to the node side js and then I need to get back the returned json object back to the front-end. I was hoping if anyone could point me in the right direction and explain to me how it works as I'm trying to learn. I'm running everything locally on my machine.

Get keyword from Angular form. 
Execute. 
Return Json object from js on node. 
Send object over to angular component.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802813/how-to-make-ajax-call-with-angular2ts So learn about AJAX and how it is used in angular2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. how would you rate my noobness on a scale from 1-10 ?

Comment: It's not about noobness, it's about your desire to learn. :) Hope the tutorials help.

Comment: Indeed it helped. Thank You. :)