# How can I hit Asp.net Core Api from Angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.net Core and Angular 2. I created my angular 2 setup, and its working fine. But when I try to hit My WebApi I'm not able to hit.

```
namespace Angular2Application8.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Hello")]    
    public class HelloController : Controller
    {
        StudentContext db = new StudentContext();

        [HttpGet]    
        public string Ghouse()
        {
            var x = from n in db.StudentMaster
                    select n;
            return "Hello Ghouse";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to hit my controller at `http://localhost:1473/api/Hello/Ghouse`

Comment: Is your Angular app hosted by the same host of your API ?

Comment: Yes it hosted in same

Comment: Please, edit your question to include any error messages you are getting in the browser console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make AJAX call with angular2(ts)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802813/how-to-make-ajax-call-with-angular2ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` for all `Controllers` so when your `controller` name is `HelloController` and `method` `GHouse` your url should be `api/hello/ghouse`

Also make sure you have properly configurated [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing).

Answer (score 0):

The attribute routes in the example do not allow you to hit the desired URL.

You need to update the route template or change the URL you call.

```
[Route("api/Hello")]
public class HelloController : Controller {
    StudentContext db = new StudentContext();
    [HttpGet] // Matches GET api/Hello
    [HttpGet("Ghouse")] // Matches GET api/Hello/Ghouse
    public string Ghouse() {
        var x = from n in db.StudentMaster
                select n;
        return "Hello Ghouse";
    }
}
```